# My crankset stops the pedals from turning when I tighten it onto the bottom bracket

Tags: crankset

This sounds like a stupid question however, I'm pretty sure I took these cranks off my current set up before. I wanted to ask if there is such a thing as a spacer on the bb axel ever that I might be missing?

Shimano stronglight double crank.

Square drive BB 68 shell. I'll have to check the axel.

Usually I would presume that the crank axel is too short, but the space between the crank and chainstay is fine.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How can you expect a quality answer with no specifics such as type of bb and and what model crank.

Comment: You're question is unclear.  When you tighten the crank arm onto the shaft can you tell what, if anything, is binding?  It kinda looks like the crank arm and BB cup are designed to "nest" to produce a seal.  Do they indeed seem to "nest"?  Why did you take the crank arm off, and what have you done to the BB bearings since taking the arm off?

Comment: yes the problem is also unclear. the bevelled area around where the axel fits on the crank is binding with the bb shell black area in the photo, which is causing it to stop going round. I took the crank off to change it for a different crank and now I want ot put it back again. I've done nothing to the BB bearings as far as I can remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no BB Spacer for a square taper crankset (and is a very bad idea to start). 
From the image, it looks like you have an (square) ISO crank on an JIS (low profile) spindle. I can see the outer square of the crank was severely deformed.

There is not much you can do but to start thinking of changing the crankset, or keep holding on to it til the day it depart.

[image]

Edit:

Sorry, I missed your question. But before answering, can I ask you to check:

- If the crankset touches the BB?
- If it is a dead-lock or a severe friction on the spinning of your crankset?
- If it makes noise when you try to spin the crankset on the BB?

Comment: any idea what bottom bracket woudl be compatible with FC-S125 cranks

Comment: according to this looks like 119mm english http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=c50c795c-1016-4021-8ae8-9f68450fde36

Comment: I see from the website it is JIS tapered, your BB spindle I suspect is 'JIS low profile' spindle. Maybe your crankset taper hole was widen enough that it come closer to the BB and create problems

Comment: I think thats the answer

Comment: If you are going to buy a new crankset, I would highly recommend you spare another £8-£15 for a good compatible BB with that crankset. 
There might be problems with the old BB spindle that would create problems to your new crankset.

Answer (score 0):

There are not spacers that can be placed between the axle and the crank.  It's a high stress location.

Did you take the BB out?  Is it in the same position (right-left)?  Does it turn freely with the cranks off?

Comment: looking at the pic above the housing of the bb on the crank size is quite wide.

Comment: I was thinking the same: Did you take the axle out and put it back left side to the right? The axle is not symmetric!